# How to train a machine to label individual words in a text

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, nlp, text-mining

For a text (say):

"I am leaving India today. I am headed to USA for a week."
"I am travelling from India to USA"

I need to train the machine to label USA as "Destination" and India as "Source"

I am using SpaCy's NER to extract the locations.

How should I proceed to create a training set and train it. What would be my feature vector and label vector?

Comment: You will need to find the pattern in the following text I can see that company names comes  before every keyword "company" , I can extract those and maintain dictionary with values .More superior is the company

Comment: Thanks for the reply @HariomSingh. I have edited my ques a bit. What if the company names are just ABC and XYZ (like google or microsoft). And can you  elaborate your solution on assigning values. (I need to use either NLP/ML if possible)

Comment: Although the task as put is a bit vague you definitely will need to get familiar with a few concepts in natural language processing. Definitely you will need named entity recognition, something that is provided by a few of the popular nlp libraries e.g NLTK. Also you will need a lot of training data to teach your models to recognize the difference between source and destination (ones you have found the locations in your corpus).

Comment: Thank you for the reply @IvayloStrandjev. I had used Spacy library and its NER feature to extract the locations. But I am not able to get an idea of how to train it.

Comment: @Phoenix probably you would want to train a classifier on the Location predicting 3 classes 'source', 'destination' and 'other'. There are multiple ways to define such a classifier, one popular approach would be with recurrent neural networks and attention. Also an extension is dynamic memory networks for questions answering. Have a look at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3octNTE7Is

Answer (score 0):

One approach that I think may be promising is using Dynamic Memory Networks for Questions Answering. The problem they are solving is generalized version of what you are attempting to solve. In your case you would be answering just two questions: "Which is the source?" and "Which is the destination?". Have a look at the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.01417) and also this [video lecture](http://youtube.com/watch?v=T3octNTE7Is) that explains the same approach.

Seems to me it should be easy to generate a training set as long as you have enough training examples with ground truth for source and destination.

You could also make use of the fact you are only dealing with 2 different questions - instead of computing embedding for the question, train two different models, one for answering which is the source and second that find the destination.

Comment: @Thank you so much.. I'll look into everything you said and will be back to thank you again once complete the task.